# Drobo-FS config files exhibiting input/ouput error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, samba, smb, drobo

I have a Drobo-FS with DropBear installed via DroboApps which allows me SSH access into the linux operating system which powers the Drobo-FS.

The Drobo-FS file system has a directory which looks like this

```
# ls /mnt/DroboFS/System
DNAS    avahi    netatalk    samba
```

Each of the directories listed has a `conf` or similar directory within it and for me the `samba`, `netatalk` and `avahi` conf files all exhibit an `Input/ouput error`

```
# ls /mnt/DroboFS/System/samba/conf
ls: /mnt/DroboFS/System/samba/conf/scratch.smb.conf: Input/output error
ls: /mnt/DroboFS/System/samba/conf/smb.conf: Input/output error

# ls /mnt/DroboFS/System/netatalk/conf
ls: /mnt/DroboFS/System/netatalk/conf/afpd.conf: Input/output error
ls: /mnt/DroboFS/System/netatalk/conf/AppleVolumes.default: Input/output error

# ls /mnt/DroboFS/System/avahi/conf
ls: /mnt/DroboFS/System/avahi/conf/scratch.avahi-daemon.conf: Input/output error
avahi-daemon.conf
```

I have read that this behaviour is indicitive of a hard-drive failure or a loose cable (I assume connecting the drive to the controller.) However this is not an ordinary Linux box, so my first question is

***What device is /mnt/DroboFS/System stored on***. I assume it cannot be on a hard-drive in any bay, and must therefore be on some other internal drive or flash memory. If so does this mean my Drobo-FS is faulty?

Also the question has to be asked: **why have only the configuration files been affected?**

Or could this problem run deeper?

---

***Additionally could anyone with specifically a Drobo-FS and frimware version 1.2.0 provide their versions of the following files?***

```
/mnt/DroboFS/System/samba/conf/smb.conf
/mnt/DroboFS/System/netatalk/conf/afpd.conf
/mnt/DroboFS/System/netatalk/conf/AppleVolumes.default
```

With that I could replace the seemingly corrupt files with the correct versions.

---

And finally, if the Drobo itself is faulty, is the RAID (or BeyondRAID) configuration data stored within the hard drives themselves or the drobo. In other words **can I move the existing drives to a new drobo without data loss?**

**Edit:** I can answer my own question here. I discovered this is possible if you move all Drobo disks as a "disk pack" to a new Drobo. The order/position of each drive must to be maintained for this to work.

---

**Edit:** Result of `cat /proc/mounts`

```
# cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / jffs2 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw 0 0
/dev/shm /dev/shm tmpfs rw 0 0
/dev/mtdblock/2 /var jffs2 rw 0 0
/dev/sda1 /mnt/DroboFS ext3 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered 0 0
```

Comment: what does `cat /proc/mounts` say?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the result.

Comment: Sorry no one's gotten the answer to your question yet. I've got a DroboFS, let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: @bobmagoo I am still having the same issues, although I can now coexist with them. I have since had my entire DroboFS replaced, and the problem still persists.

Comment: @MarcusWhybrow Sounds good. Sorry to hear you're still having issues, hopefully it isn't causing any issues using the thing.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, you should post the answer for the benefit of anyone else looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: How right you are @BenWest. If that were only the case.

Comment: I misread above, you say you've answered what must be a related question; that's my mistake.

Is your device malfunctioning? or are you simply unable to access the files when using what might be considered an unorthodox manner?

Answer (score 1):

`ls -ld /mnt/DroboFS/System` should tell you and allow you to identify which device it is; if it ain't a symlink to something else it is more likely be the case that your hard drive is faulty so you might need to replace it, assuming the cable is properly connected and intact.